# Html 5 wysiwyg designer

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

I am looking for wysiwyg designer that creates applications in html 5 (based on any major JavaScript library like JQueryUI or other).

So far, the only thing I found is Ext Designer:
http://www.sencha.com/products/designer/
but it is still in very early stage and with serious limitations (custom components can not be  added to toolbox for example).

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Atlas](http://280atlas.com/what.php) a development tool for building Cappuccino applications. [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/) apps are written in objectiv-j and will be compiled so they run as Html/JavaScript Applications.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since the HTML5 spec is very recently, and not all parts of it have been accepted/finished, I think it'll take sometime until we got a good wysiwyg editor for it, specially with support for any js library.

Comment: "HTML5" can mean many things. Ext Designer at the moment is solidly "HTML4" since it's targeted at desktop browsers from IE6 onward. You can read more about HTML5 here: http://www.sencha.com/blog/2010/05/23/html5-now-with-20-percent-more-internet/

Comment: I think you are right, what I had in mind is more JavaScript + Css, probably better called RIA but also an important part for building html 5 apps.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard good things about [Aloha](http://aloha-editor.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at [Maqetta](http://maqetta.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I just tried out the HP/Palm/webOS Ares IDE, which lets you click and drag GUI elements and hook them up to JavaScript events.  This is targeted at webOS devices, in that you can make JavaScript calls outside of the browser sandbox (similar to PhoneGap).  But they claim they are targeting cross-platform web apps.

Today they announced Enyo, which is the next generation of this, which claims to have vast improvements.  I'm excited to evaluate it for general purpose HTML5 web app development.